# Recognizing users in user page with Sessions in php

Tags: php, session

Hopefully, an easy question for this board. Also, bear in mind, I am a beginner. So, if there's some **huge** step I'm missing, please let me know.

What I want to do is set a user page to recognize a user's email after he inputs on the login page. As you'll see, I'm using FatCow hosting, and edited my password/username and any other personal data. Here's the code I have, your help is much appreciated:

**Login Page:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['submitted'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $link = mysql_connect('root.fatcowmysql.com', 'username', 'password'); 
    if (!$link) { 
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
    } 

    if ($email&&$password) 
    { 
        mysql_select_db(lcmembership); 

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' && password='$password'");

        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if($numrows !=0)
        {
            session_save_path('/home/users/web/b2582/username/phpsessions'); 
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['users'] = "test";
            header("location: users.php");
        }
        else
            echo ("<p style='position: absolute; left: 500px; top: 150px; font-family: arial;color: white; background-color: #F1433F; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px;'>That email address doesn't exist in our records. </p>");
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        echo ("<p style='position: absolute; left: 500px; top: 150px; font-family: arial;color: white; background-color: #F1433F; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px; '>Incorrect Password. </p>");
    }
}
?>
<html>Form here with Action="" and Method="Post"</html>
```

**User Page:**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['users'];
?>
```

Comment: Also, I'm setting the Session to "test" to test if I can echo on the user page.  No luck, so far!

Comment: Just curious. Why are you setting the session save path? The PHP default should be sufficient. Are you receiving any errors? Does it successfully redirect to users.php?

Comment: Also, you have two else{} statements for the same if() block. You can't check both email and password because you only have one SQL statement.

Comment: i set the session save path after reading some FAQ on FatCow hosting.  I have tried it with and without a save path defined.

Comment: it does successfully redirect, what should the else statements look like?  Do you think that could be causing the echo problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a custom session_save_path() like you are then you also need to call it out on your other pages. The method is both a getter and setter.

So on your User Page you need the following:

```
<?php
    session_save_path(); // Get session path
    session_start(); // Resume session
    echo $_SESSION['users'];
?>
```

Also you need to correct your else logic. You have two else statements within one if chain. You need to do else if for the first one and then you can default at the end with else. Personally though I'd move the email and password logic up further in your code. It's redundant where you have it now based on the fact that your MySQL queries are only looking for records where both match.

Comment: Worked!  Thanks for the advice - you are awesome.  I will clean up the else logic too.